# Stream only seems to have 1 chunk when using parse: false in Hapi multipart/form-data

Tags: node.js, parsing, stream, multipartform-data, hapi

I have an endpoint that receives a stream:

```
    server.route({
    method: 'PUT',
    path: `${FILES_PREFIX}`,
    handler: Handlers.createFile,
    options: {
        description: 'Create file.',
        tags: ['api', 'file'],
        payload: {
            timeout: false,
            maxBytes: 10 * GB,
            output: 'stream',
            multipart: true,
            parse: false,
            allow: 'multipart/form-data',
        }
    }
});
```

If I set parse: true I receive my buffer as expected and can read it on payload.data. However, since my files are too big, I need to parse it on my own (otherwise I get: RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "length" is out of range. It must be >= 0 && <= 2147483647. Received 2877227008)

So the solution I'm trying is to set parse: false and parse the stream myself. However, when I look at my payload I see I have readableBuffer() that returns me a buffer list... but the buffer list only has 1 element of 64kb. The first element .next value is null. I'm just left there asking where is the rest of my data.

I also tried looking at request.raw.req, since parsing is false I shouldn't have all the data in a buffer anyway... but it's basically the same information in request.raw.req and request.payload. I also have the readableBuffer of 64kb on request.raw.req().readableBuffer()

Answer (score 1):

The default parser is definitely not suitable for transfers of that size, as it buffers all incoming data into memory.

You are on the right track, but you are not using the stream API as intended. The `readableBuffer()` method only returns what is currently buffered. To receive more data and properly consume it, you will need to use an appropriate stream API:

1. Using `'data` & `'end'` events.
2. Using `stream.read()` with the `'readable'` event.
3. Just `stream.pipe()` it to another stream.

For all of these you will need to register for and handle the `'error'` event appropriately.

The most modern approach is using the [Stream.pipeline()](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback) helper.

Finally, a stream might not be the best solution. Hapi also supports a `'file'` output mode, which will stream the input directly to a file on the disk.